# disabled browser back button google chrome and edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, location.href);

window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
    history.go(1);
    alert('Back button is not allowed.');
});
```

Show message when browser back button clicked on chrome and edge latest version above code snippet is not working.

On Firefox it works perfectly.

Please suggest any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this code and then use browser back button.

```html
<script>
  (function (global) {
    if (typeof global === "undefined") {
      throw new Error("window is undefined");
    }

    var _hash = "!";
    var noBackPlease = function () {
      global.location.href += "#";

      // making sure we have the fruit available for juice....
      // 50 milliseconds for just once do not cost much (^__^)
      global.setTimeout(function () {
        global.location.href += "!";
      }, 50);
    };

    // Earlier we had setInerval here....
    global.onhashchange = function () {
      if (global.location.hash !== _hash) {
        global.location.hash = _hash;
      }
    };

    global.onload = function () {
      noBackPlease();

      // disables backspace on page except on input fields and textarea..
      document.body.onkeydown = function (e) {
        var elm = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
        if (e.which === 8 && elm !== "input" && elm !== "textarea") {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
        // stopping event bubbling up the DOM tree..
        e.stopPropagation();
      };
    };
  })(window);
</script>
<script src="http://static.jsbin.com/js/render/edit.js?4.1.8"></script>
<script>
  jsbinShowEdit &&
    jsbinShowEdit({
      static: "http://static.jsbin.com",
      root: "http://jsbin.com",
    });
</script>
<script>
  (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i["GoogleAnalyticsObject"] = r;
    (i[r] =
      i[r] ||
      function () {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments);
      }),
      (i[r].l = 1 * new Date());
    (a = s.createElement(o)), (m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]);
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m);
  })(
    window,
    document,
    "script",
    "https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js",
    "ga"
  );

  ga("create", "UA-1656750-34", "auto");
  ga("require", "linkid", "linkid.js");
  ga("require", "displayfeatures");
  ga("send", "pageview");
</script>
```

Comment: @Sagar Bhosale Please tick if you got the answer.